# Order of the Index Elements using imakeidx and PDFLatex

Tags: indexing, pdflatex

The following program creates two indexes.

The text of the first index is given explicitely in \index{}.

The text of the second index is coming from the commands xxone, xxtwo and xxthree.
The order of the elements in the index is based on the command names not the command values
How to make sure that the command values are used?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Demo,columns=1]
\makeindex[name=test,title=Examples,columns=1]

\newcommand{\xxone}   {Example 1}
\newcommand{\xxtwo}   {Example 2}
\newcommand{\xxthree} {Example 3}

\begin{document}

\index{Example 1}
\index{Example 2}
\index{Example 3}

\index[test]{\xxone{}}
\index[test]{\xxtwo{}}
\index[test]{\xxthree{}}

\lipsum[1]

\printindex
\printindex[test]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399435/imakeidx-order-if-own-command-is-used-to-specify-index-entry

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcommand{\nindex}[2][]{\index[test]{#2}}

\makeindex[title=Demo,columns=1]
\makeindex[name=test,title=Examples,columns=1]

\newcommand{\xxone}   {Example 1}
\newcommand{\xxtwo}   {Example 2}
\newcommand{\xxthree} {Example 3}

\begin{document}

\index{Example 1}
\index{Example 2}
\index{Example 3}


\nindex[test]{\xxone{}}
\nindex[test]{\xxtwo{}}
\nindex[test]{\xxthree{}}

\lipsum[1]

\printindex
\printindex[test]


\end{document}
```